# Vertex AI Endpoint Does Not Scale Up

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

**Any idea why Vertex AI is not scaling up?**

To handle online predictions, I’ve deployed a custom trained model to an endpoint with the following configurations:

```
{
  "dedicated_resources": {
    "machine_spec": {
      "machine_type": "n1-standard-8",
      "accelerator_type": "NVIDIA_TESLA_P100",
      "accelerator_count": 1
    },
    "min_replica_count": 3,
    "max_replica_count": 6,
    "autoscaling_metric_specs": [
      {
        "metric_name": "aiplatform.googleapis.com/prediction/online/cpu/utilization",
        "target": 30
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I ran traffic for over 20 minutes and the replica count / target remains at 3. I can observe in the Google console that the CPU usage on all nodes is roughly 60% (over the cpu target of 30%).  In the model settings view, I can also confirm all of these settings did indeed register correctly.

Any thoughts here?

Comment: Are you doing a batch prediction? Because...
The prediction nodes for batch prediction do not automatically scale. Vertex AI uses BatchDedicatedResources.startingReplicaCount and ignores BatchDedicatedResources.maxReplicaCount. (https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/configure-compute#scaling)

Comment: online predictions, not batch

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I should have payed more attention to the answer in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72479023/vertex-ai-endpoint-doesnt-scale-up-down). The key message is:

> Autoscaling with Vertex AI endpoints is (by default) based on the cpu utilization across all cores of the machine type you've specified. The default threshold of 60% represents 60% on all cores. For a 4 core machine, that means you need 240% utilization to trigger autoscaling.

I ended up using `aiplatform.googleapis.com/prediction/online/accelerator/duty_cycle` as a target, and found it to be very reliable.